# Incline boxplot's x labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I tried to look for a method to tilt my `boxplot` but never landed with the correct placement of the names.

I have this dataframe `Accuracy`of different accuracies for each model, I want to display the variability in a boxplot.

```
  sample iteration poly_eps.001_C1 poly_eps.01_C1 poly_eps.1_C1 poly_eps.001_C10 poly_eps.01_C10
(int)     (int)           (dbl)          (dbl)         (dbl)            (dbl)           (dbl)
    1         1       0.9841270      0.9841270     0.9761905        0.9761905       0.9761905
    1         2       0.9680000      0.9680000     0.9520000        0.9600000       0.9600000
    1         3       0.9523810      0.9523810     0.9603175        0.9365079       0.9365079
    1         4       0.9600000      0.9600000     0.9600000        0.9520000       0.9520000
    1         5       0.9523810      0.9523810     0.9682540        0.9444444       0.9444444
```

Then my code to

```
     # algorithms helpsvme only getting the desired features for the boxplot
  algorithms = names(accuracies_table[-c(1:2)])  

  boxplot(accuracies_table[algorithms], col = color ,
      main = "Polynomial KSVM Models", ylab = "Accuracy",
      las=2,ylim = c(0.90,1))
```

[image]

could someone help me incline the x axis labels? or how could this be done in ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(accuracies_table[algorithms])
ggplot(df, aes(variable, value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() +
        ggtitle("Polynomial KSVM Models") + ylab("Accuracy") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size=15, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works just fine, any insight where I could get a good tutorial of these? I'm impressed with the application of the melt function for this purpose. Thank you!